# Method to check if array element in Array contains a false

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, filter

I have a state which contains this array. I'm trying to write a method that goes through every element in the "report" array and checks the "sets" array to see if "completed" is true. I'm looking for code that is clean. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Take a look at `Array.prototype.every()` and `Array.prototype.some()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over `Object.values` of each object with `Array#some`.

```
const notCompleted = Object.values(obj.report)
     .some(({sets})=>sets.some(({completed})=>!completed));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work in your case :

```js
const reports = [
  {
    sets: 
    [
      {
        completed: true
      },
      {
        completed: true
      } 
    ]
  },
  {
    sets: 
    [
      {
        completed: true
      },
      {
        completed: true
      } 
    ]
  },
  {
    sets: 
    [
      {
        completed: true
      },
      {
        completed: true
      } 
    ] 
  }
]


const isTrue = reports.reduce((acc, report) => {
  return acc ? report.sets.every((el) => el.completed === true) : false;
}, true);

console.log(isTrue);
```